# Why in the case of free particle we are not taking sine and cosine in the solution of the wave function whereas in the case of 1D box we are using?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, boundary-conditions

why in the case of free particle we are not taking sine and cosine as the solutions of the wave function whereas in the case of 1D box we are using it?

Comment: it would help the question if you included the eigenstates in it, e.g. the PIAB is $|n\rangle=\sin{n\pi x/L}$ while a free particle is $|k\rangle \propto \exp(ikx) = \cos{kx} + i\sin{kx}$.

Comment: Boundary conditions? You will need to provide the actual equation you are trying to solve and the boundary conditions for that equation. I am guessing it will be scattering boundary conditions for a free particle and vanishing function boundary conditions for the box.

Answer (score 1):

For a spatial region with a constant potential energy function $V(x)=V_1$, and $E>V_1$, the SWE has a general solution of $$\psi(x)=A\sin (k_1x)+ B\cos (k_1x),\tag{1}$$
where $A$ and $B$ will be determined by boundary conditions and normalization, and $k_1=\sqrt{\frac{2m(E-V_1)}{\hbar^2}} $.

But that's not the only mathematical form of the solution. One can also write
$$\psi(x)=Ce^{ik_1x}+De^{-ik_1x},\tag{2}$$
and this is a completely equivalent solution, where $C$ and $D$ are related to $A$ and $B$, and by Euler's formula $$e^{ibx}=\cos (bx) + i\sin (bx). \hspace{1cm} b \in \mathcal{C}$$

The choice of using one form over the other is entirely left to the user, but often it is easier mathematically to manipulate one rather than the other, depending on the boundary conditions.

It's perfectly acceptable to start with (2) for the particle in a box, then apply the boundary conditions. Using Euler's formula and normalization you will get exactly the same solution as if you started with (1). In fact, if you have a PIAB extending from $x_0 \ne 0$ to $x_0+L \ne 0$, using (2) is the way to go.

In cases of step functions and scattering solutions, it's often easier to use (1) as the starting point.

Bottom line: It's your choice where to start, then apply the boundary conditions and other specified constraints for the problem at hand.